# Remote access using C# application to database created using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I have a database called `Library` created in SQL Server 2014 under my locally created server instance. I am using that database as the datasource in my windows form application. It is working perfectly when on my computer, but when I run it on other machines, it stops with the error

> Unhandled exception occurred...
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - could not open connection to SQL Server)

I have started all services from configuration manager and have enabled tcp/ip under protocols for `MSSQLSERVER`. Is there any way I can accomplish this, or do I have to shift to local db?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your connection string includes your remote machine name as part of the "Data Source", so something like :
    connectionString="Data Source=machinename\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Integrated Security=True"

note that this connection string will target a db name "mydbname", under the machine machinename which has a SQL Express instance.

if that didn't work let me see your connection string.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what "configuration string" you are talking about? and my cannection string at present is:
'Data Source=NILADRI-HP;Initial Catalog=BookLibrary;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False'

Comment: Hi Nil, I mean connection string, Now looking to your connection string, you are using your windows credentials to access the remote database, so make sure that using your Windows Username/password you can connect to the NILADRI-HP and fully access "BookLibrary" database through SQL Management Studio, if you can't you need to connect for example using a user name/password setup on the NILADRI machine with read/write access to BookLibrary database.